# graded k-algebras

Tags: representation-theory

Suppose we are given a positively graded $k$-algebra $A$ such that $A_i=0$, for $i\neq 0,1$ (i.e $A=A_0\oplus A_1$). Suppose furthermore all $A_i$ are finite dimensional as $k$ vector spaces and that the global dimension of $A_0$ is finite. Do we have $\mathrm{gldim}(A)<\infty$?

Comment: Of course not. Take $A_0=A_1=k$.

Comment: Also known as $k[x]/(x^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Summing up the comments as a CW answer:

No, this is not the case. For example take $A=k[x]/(x^2)$ with $\operatorname{deg}(x)=1$. Then $A_0=k$ is one-dimensional and of finite global dimension, $A_1=kx$ is one-dimensional. But $A$ is self-injective, hence of infinite global dimension.